# How to align the widget to the center of the screen

Tags: html, css, widget

I am trying to align this widget in my webpage.

[image: widget]

Widget code -

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"><script>var getJSON = function(url) {return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.open("get", url, true);xhr.responseType = "json";xhr.onload = function() {var status = xhr.status;if (status == 200) {resolve(xhr.response);}else{reject(status);}};xhr.send();});};getJSON("https://www.wedmegood.com/api/v1/vendor/review_widget_detail?version=1.1&vendor_id=19098").then(function(data){document.getElementById("profile-name").innerHTML = data.data.vendor_name;if(data.data.reviews_count == 1)document.getElementById("review-count").innerHTML = data.data.reviews_count + " Review";else
document.getElementById("review-count").innerHTML = data.data.reviews_count + " Reviews";var res = data.data.profile_pic_url.replace("%%", "270");document.getElementById("img-rep").src = res;}, function(status) {});</script><style>p{font-family:proxima-nova;font-style: bold;}.img-circle{border-radius:50%;position:absolute;z-index: 1;height:70px;width:70px;left:20px;top:18px;}.box{position:relative;box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);height:150px;width:300px;}</style></head><body><a href="https://www.wedmegood.com/profile/Wedding-Moments-115322" target="_newtab"><div class="box"><img id="img-rep" class="img-circle" src=""><p id="profile-name" style = "color:#e72e77;position:absolute;left:110px;font-size:18px;"></p><p id="review-count" style = "color:white;position:absolute;left:208px;top:48px;font-size:15px;"></p><img src="https://images.wedmegood.com/images/widget.jpg"><p style="position:absolute;font-size:14px;top:152px;left:67px;">View My Profile on WedMegood</p></div></a></body></html>
```

But when I am putting it in my webpage, I am not able to align it to the center. It should be in the same vertical position as **View More** and **Awards**. See this picture -
[image: off-center]

I am putting the widget code inside an html element. There are three columns and I am putting the widget in the middle -
[image: design element]

But the widget is not exactly at the center. Can you please tell me how to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance ....

Comment: Hi! can you tell me what did you try

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying back. I modified all the positions from relative/absolute to center. Played with them, but the issue was not resloved. CSS is already used in the existing widget code, but `justify-content:center` has really nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put you widget into a wrapper div . add a class to that div . for eg. `.wrapper`
make wrapper width 100% and set `justify-content:center`

```html
<div class="wrapper">
//widget code here
</div>
```

**css**

```css
.wrapper{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
width:100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. While this didn't work as it is, I copied the css content under the box style and it has aligned the box perfectly in the center. Thanks a ton!